# NotImplementedError: the null tvtk.pyface.ui.null backend doesn't implement scene_editor:SceneEditor

Tags: pyqt5, mayavi, mayavi.mlab, notimplementedexception, pyface

i want to visualize my calibration and I am using pyqt5==5.12.3 When I type following command:
python3 scripts/interface.py --config configs/config.yaml

I get this error:
NotImplemented error: the null tvk.pyface.ui.null backend doesn’t implement scene editor:Scene Editor

I tried it with wxpython and update pyqt but it didn’t work. I also installed all needed packages.

Answer (score 0):

just stumbled upon the same when visualising my results; according to Mayavi docs:

As of the latest release, i.e. 4.6.0 and above, if you are using Python 3.x and are on a 64 bit machine, installation via pip is the easiest and is as follows:

$ pip install mayavi

$ pip install PyQt5

...just install the latter (PyQt5-5.15.9 PyQt5-Qt5-5.15.2 PyQt5-sip-12.12.1) and all your problems will vanish into thin air